# Ruby/Rails - Forum signature images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick

I would like my Rails app to somehow generate forum signature images, like this one:
[image]

I couldn't really find anything on Google. Have anyone seen any kind of implementation of this in Ruby (I'm guessing with ImageMagick) ?

If not, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried rMagick? Is an interface between ruby and ImageMagick...
The URL is: http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

For doing that sort of image creation, RMagick (the Ruby interface to ImageMagick) is probably going to be your best bet.

http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/

That said, think carefully about how you're going to implement this.  You're probably NOT going to render these types of complex images on-the-fly, during the course of a web request, or your application is going to become very sluggish.  Consider using a scheduled job that will render these images a few times a day at most.

Comment: I'm aware of this and was thinking to do a cron job once a day. Thanks!